# Trouble building Assimp library for MinGW

Tags: c++, cmake

Hi I am trying to build [Assimp 5.0.1](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases/tag/v5.0.1) using cmake and MinGW-Makefiles on Windows. In the according folder I do the following.

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../
```

The output tells me to update MinGW:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW64/bin/gcc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW64/bin/g++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Shared libraries enabled
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:266 (message):
  MinGW is too old to be supported.  Please update MinGW and try again.
```

On my System I have two MinGW folders. `C:/MinGW64/bin/gcc.exe` the folder which the cmake process seems to check and `C:/MinGW` which is the 32-bit version I assume.

Google for `Update MinGW` always points to `C:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\guimain.exe` which I did use. Here I do not get any further updates:

[image]

Also as far as I get it cmake is checking the `MinGW64` folder and not the one I am updating. Also I actually want to be able to build assimp for both 64 and 32-bit. So how would I update both the `MinGW` and the `MinGW64` versions?

Comment: CMake finds `gcc` as `C:/MinGW64/bin/gcc.exe` and that is version 4.8.3. That's a *very* old version. My suggestion is that you uninstall *both* variants of MinGW, and then download the latest and freshest release to reinstall.

Comment: You may want to use msys2 and get the latest mingw and also package management as assimp is a package in msys2: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-assimp](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-assimp) to install from your msys2 terminal type `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-assimp` Here is a link to msys2: [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)